# Quarkus Resteasy reactive missing builditem?

Tags: java, quarkus, resteasy, quarkus-rest-client

I am upgrading my extension to quarkus 2.9.0 and migrating to resteasy reactive.

Some of existing builditems in resteasy classic do not exist anymore in reactive implementation. I was using `ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem` to record an `ExceptionMapper` and a `ClientRequestFilter`.

For my `ExceptionMapper`, I use now an `ExceptionMapperBuildItem` without any problem. But for my `ClientRequestFilter`, I do not know which builditem i have to choose (there is no such a ClientRequestFilterBuildItem)

Maybe am I missing something obvious ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClientRequestFilter` for the REST Client are registered  via `@RegisterProvider`, so no build item is needed

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why is it a difference between registering ClientRequestFilter and for example ContainerRequestFilter which needs a build item ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the quesion? I don't really understand what you are asking

Comment: Why is there a BuiltItem for a ContainerRequestFilter and not for a ClientRequestFilter ?

Comment: Because the latter is never needed

Comment: But if I am writing a QuarkusApplication, I can have a ClientRequestFilter registered in the application that will modify requests without annotating the interfaces (which aren't under my control - I could inherit from them, but I rather wouldn't have that boilerplate code), whereas I'm not sure I can do that with code coming from an extension?

Comment: You can certainly open an issue asking for the feature

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue; I wanted to use an extension to instrument an application and add request and response filters. For the `ContainerResponseFilter`, I used a `ContainerResponseFilterBuildItem` to register it.

For the `ClientRequestFilter`, I was a bit stuck. I eventually had success using a `RegisterProviderAnnotationInstanceBuildItem`. What this process is doing is an extension-side version of what the manual process would be; find classes annotated with `@RestClient`, and add a `@RegisterProvider(ClientFilter.class)`:

```
    private static final DotName CLIENT_FILTER = DotName.createSimple(ClientFilter.class.getName());
    private static final DotName REGISTER_REST_CLIENT = DotName.createSimple("org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient");


    @BuildStep
    void clientFilterSupport(CombinedIndexBuildItem indexBuildItem, BuildProducer<GeneratedBeanBuildItem> generatedBean,
                             BuildProducer<RegisterProviderAnnotationInstanceBuildItem> producer) {

        Collection<AnnotationInstance> instances = indexBuildItem.getIndex().getAnnotations(REGISTER_REST_CLIENT);
        for (AnnotationInstance instance : instances) {

            final AnnotationValue valueAttr = createClassValue(CLIENT_FILTER);

            String targetClass = instance.target().asClass().name().toString();
            producer.produce(new RegisterProviderAnnotationInstanceBuildItem(targetClass, AnnotationInstance.create(
                    DotNames.REGISTER_PROVIDER, instance.target(), List.of(valueAttr))));
        }
    }
```

The helper for making annotation values is just

```
    private AnnotationValue createClassValue(DotName filter) {
        return AnnotationValue.createClassValue("value",
                Type.create(filter, Type.Kind.CLASS));
    }
```

I also told CDI about the filter:

```
    @BuildStep
    void beans(BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> producer) {
          producer.produce(AdditionalBeanBuildItem.unremovableOf(ClientFilter.class));
    }
```